# CSV import in RStudio

Tags: r

```
> meta_test2<- read.csv("~/Dropbox/Buck Files/Fertility_new/Metabolomics_meta.csv" , header = TRUE)
```

Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  :
invalid multibyte string at 'l '
This error occurs in RStudio on my Mac but works perfectly on Windows10. I am guessing that "read.csv" is coming from different packages but I can't confirm. I also do not know how to  find a multibyte string at  or where that is in the file. Furthermore, when I change to header=FALSE, it also works on the Mac.

New code that works, but why is it successful while read.csv is not?

```
readr::read_csv("~/Dropbox/Buck Files/Fertility_new/Metabolomics_meta.csv")
```

Comment: impossible to bughunt without reproducible sample data, code and environment.

Comment: also, you could try `data.table::fread()` for reading the csv data and see if the error persists

Comment: probably an encoding issue. Mac and Windows use different defaults. Try adding the argument `encoding = "latin-1"`

Comment: Mr. Wimpel: I have not found a way to upload my data. I know that would have helped. You do have my code but not my environment. How can I provide that? Some further information: when I click on the file in RStudio files pane, I am offered the opportunity to create a dataFrame, which it does successfully. Even though I can go on with my project, my concern remains as to why there is a problem at all.

Comment: I would open the csv and remove all lined but the first two beforedoing the import. If it works, repeat the process and remove less lines... Until you understand what line (if any) creates first the issue. It's likely that `read.csv` infers a column type from a fewer selection of rows and then can't convert. (e.g. a column that starts with 1, 7, 3, 6, ..., "hello" where `read.csv` thinks it's a numeric column and try to convert "hello" as a numeric.

Comment: Mr.? tic-toc_choc: I have not yet implemented your suggestion but examined the output of spec(Metabolomics_meta), which was obtained successfully via readr::read_csv   It shows: 10 "col_character()" and 9 "col_double()". All exactly as I expected when examining the original .csv file. Would you still recommend that I go through the process you outlined?  I am really trying to understand what additional capability readr::read_csv adds to read.csv that makes the former successful while the latter is not.